# Creating Cut Scenes For iPad

Tags: ipad, cutscene

I am working on an iPad game, and would like to have a few, pre-rendered cut scenes that are shown at key moments throughout the game.

How do low-budget software developers create pre-rendered cut scenes, especially when the target device is an iPad?

Comment: Are you asking how to create the cut-scenes (what software to use etc.) or how to add/integrate them into the game?

Comment: I am asking, how can I create cut-scenes, keeping in mind I really have no budget (a development company of 1 hobbyist developer). I am not worried about the integration part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common method is to record a movie, encode it to a file such as Mpeg-4, and use the iPhone's selection of video controls to play that movie back.

The movie itself can be produced in a variety of ways:

e.g.

- Live action;
- Computer generated images using a CGI package such as Autodesk's 3ds Max or Maya;
- Play out your scene using your own game and record it using something like FRAPS.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest paintings with subtle animations in a comic like presentation.
If you are lucky you might find a talented young artist that will spend his/her free time to get their art exposed in a game.

A good example of awesome "2D" cutscenes are the mini-cutscenes before missions in Warhammer40k: Chaos Rising. It's basically paintings overlain on an animated 2D mesh. Very clerver, good looking and affordable! I can't find a video example online though. Most of the ones online are full 3D.